# w3 schools form tutorial doesnt send email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am trying to set up a form for my website that is all on 1 php page (contact.php). I have went through the tutorial on w3schools and have gotten the form validation working perfectly. However, it does not send the form information anywhere. I have researched other form articles and tutorials, and although I can get some forms to email, they dont validate, and vice versa. I have tried combining this info, but it does not work.

Can someone please help me to get this code to send the form data to an email address?

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $orgErr = $emailErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $org = $email = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["org"])) {
     $orgErr = "Organization is required";
   } else {
     $org = test_input($_POST["org"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$org)) {
       $orgErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
     if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
     $website = "";
   } else {
     $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }

}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name*: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Organization*: <input type="text" name="org" value="<?php echo $org;?>">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $orgErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail*: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nowhere in that code do you have anything to send email. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: should read and try to understand the code before posting on so..

Comment: I'm more shocked that the question does not have any closure votes..

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. I realize that there is no mail function. When I added it, it would mail the form but not validate it. I removed what I had, only showing the finished tutorial, and I hoped to get an answer on where to place it to have the form function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try after your checks to use the following function:

```
mail();
```

Reference:
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: 1) His code had come from there so I referred back to it.
2) In which way is it not reliable?

Comment: Additionally, please do not post comments or only links as answers.

Comment: It was neither a comment nor just links, the answer is there. he's missing the mail function.

Comment: @johnconde for reference, w3fools returns to a default page, should look to find a new,source to slander such a perfect website. Y'know, the one with injection vulnerabilities and dated tutorials ;)

Comment: @mbacklas, in the way that the own W3C recommend **not** to use it.